# EPiServer 6 r2- Share content with another episerver site

Tags: content-management-system, episerver, episerver-6-r2

I  have two separate episerver websites with their own separate editors (separate CMS DBs).  There is some common content that both websites should share. I want to maintain the common content on website1 and use it on website 2. I don't want to export/import.

Is there any way to share content in the above scenario?thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider 3 approaches

**1. Content Mirroring**

Episerver provides content mirroring for sharing content.
Website1 would be the source site, and website2 would be the target site. Note that mirroring in CMS 6 requires Enterprise licenses.Here are some good resources on mirroring setup:

https://andersnordby.wordpress.com/2013/01/14/setting-up-mirroring-2-0-in-a-cms-6-r2-environment/

http://epiwiki.se/configuration/setting-up-mirroring-2-for-episerver-6

**2. Expose Content as RSS**

Exposing your content from website1 as an RSS feed and consuming the feed on website2.
This way, content would be maintained at website1, and website2 would just read the content - it would not be imported into website2.

http://world.episerver.com/FAQ/Items/What-is-RSS-and-how-does-it-work-in-EPiServer/

**3. Custom Page Provider**

Implementing a custom page provider to share content from website1 to website2. 
This way, content would be maintained at website1, but the content would be shared to website2 and would appear in the page tree as if it was part of the site.
Custom page providers also require Enterprise lisences.

http://sdk.episerver.com/library/cms6/Developers%20Guide/Advanced%20Features/Page%20Providers/Page%20Providers.htm